# Dynamically input Array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I want to create a two dimension array. Users will input # rows and # columns. I don't why I got "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when compiling.

#include
    using namespace std;

```
int main(){
  int **array;
  int x,y;
  cout<<"input dimention rows*columns  "<<endl;
  cin>>y>>x;
 * array=new int[y];
  for (int i=0; i<y;i++){array[i]=new int[x];}
  for (int i=0;i<y;i++){
    for (int n=0;n<x;n++){
      array[i][n]=(i+1)*(n+1);
    }}
  cout<<array[1][2]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your current solution also does not `delete[]` the arrays. This means the memory will be occupied forever, until the program ends. Which is fine for this mini program, but an absolute no-go for any slightly more complex program.

Comment: If you are using C++, you  `std::vector` from the `<vector>` header.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
*array=new int[y];
```

you haven't allocated any memory for `array` to point at. You would need to make `array` point to a size `y` array of pointers to `int`.

But you could implement this safely using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead of dynamically allocated arrays.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> (y, std::vector<int>(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
* array=new int[y];
```

Here you're dereferecing `array` but since it is uninitialized, that will cause undefined behavior.

The `*` is probably just a typo. The following will do what you wanted:

```
 array=new int*[y];
^             ^
```

I.e. create an array of int *pointers*. You can then allocate memory to each of those pointers in your first loop.

**However**, this is C++, not C, so it would be much easier to do it with just `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead of `int**`.